# geom_smooth interpolation with weights to force interpolation through the origin

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation

I am trying to run a custom defined interpolation using the custom defined `nls` function. I used a linear interpolation so as to make it easier.

I need the line to be forced to pass through the origin `(0;0)`, therefore I added the weights on the Origin point.

```
RawData <- data.frame("a" = c(0, 4, 8, 24, 28, 0, 4, 8, 24, 28, 32, 32, 48, 48), "b" = c(0, 6.67,4.44,32.22,42.67,0,0.78, 3.15, 27.56, 32.28, 46.67, 34.65, 66.67, 59.84), "Grade" = c("Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B"))


library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
View(RawData)
attach(RawData)



#I put weights so as to force lines to cross (0;0) point
RawData$weight  = ifelse(RawData$`a`==0, 100, 1)
```

Then I go ahead with the `nls` model for the interpolation:

```
nls_se <- function(formula, data, start, ...) {
  mod <- nls(formula, data, start)
  class(mod) <- "nls_se"
  mod
}

predict.nls_se <- function(model, newdata, level = 0.9, ...) {
  class(model) <- "nls"
  p <- investr::predFit(model, newdata = newdata, 
                        interval = "confidence", level = level)
  list(fit = p, se.fit = p[,3] - p[,1])
}
```

At this point, I need to make the graph. I defined a simple linear function, to make this easy:

```
Graph <- ggplot(data=RawData, aes(x=`a`, y=`b`, col=Grade)) + 
geom_point(aes(color = Grade), shape = 1, size = 2.5) +
geom_smooth(mapping = aes(weight=weight), level=0.8, method = nls_se, formula=y ~ (a * x) + b, method.args = list(start = list(a = 10, b = 5))) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196', '#33b90e'))
```

The result looks like it is ignoring the forcing on the origin point:

[image]

Note that I know that if I place "lm" as model it works properly but I would like to understand why with `nls_se` not.

```
Graph <- ggplot(data=RawData, aes(x=`a`, y=`b`, col=Grade)) + 
geom_point(aes(color = Grade), shape = 1, size = 2.5) +
geom_smooth(mapping = aes(weight=weight), level=0.8, method = lm) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196', '#33b90e'))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think if you remove the `+ b` term in your nls version it might fix your problem by not allowing an intercept other than 0

Comment: I know ... but it must be a whole way to do it without changing the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while functions like geom_smooth can be convenient in simple cases, when you need relatively more exotic things, or extra control etc, I find its better to separate out calculations from pure graphical plotting; here is an example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(investr)

RawData <- data.frame("a" = c(0, 4, 8, 24, 28, 0, 4, 8, 24, 28, 32, 32, 48, 48),
                      "b" = c(0, 6.67,4.44,32.22,42.67,0,0.78, 3.15, 27.56, 32.28, 46.67, 34.65, 66.67, 59.84), "Grade" = c("Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B"))


#I put weights so as to force lines to cross (0;0) point
RawData$weight  = ifelse(RawData$`a`==0, 10, 1)


(rawdgrps <- RawData |> group_by(Grade) |> group_split())

models <- map(rawdgrps,
              ~nls(formula=b ~ (a_ * a) + b_,
              start = list(a_ = 10, b_ = 5),
              weights = weight,
              data = .x)
              )

(predictions <- map2_dfr(models,rawdgrps,
  ~bind_cols(.y, investr::predFit(.x, newdata = .y, 
                  interval = "confidence", level = .8) 
)))


(Graph <- ggplot(data=predictions, aes(x=`a`, y=`b`, col=Grade,fill=Grade)) + 
  geom_point( shape = 1, size = 2.5) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=fit)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=.1,linetype="dotted")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#f92410','#644196')))
```

Comment: It is not working on line: `(rawdgrps <- RawData |> group_by(Grade) |> group_split())`
`Errore unexpected '>' in "(rawdgrps <- RawData |>"`

Comment: My code uses the r native pipe `|>` if you have an old version of R; you can use the traditional magrittr/dplyr pipe `%>%` instead. you can do a find replace to swap these out, though I recommend upgrading R